# user number of matches for backreference within regex

Tags: regex

I wonder if there is a possibility to use the number of matches of a group to set the quantifier for another group.

**With other words:** If a group matches 'x' times then I want to use 'x' as quantifier for another group.

**Example:**
The part, that I want to match, starts with a '(' and ends with a ')'. The text within may contain multiple '(' and ')' but always in equal number:

`1(2)3` matches `(2)`

`1(2(3(4)5)6)7` matches `(2(3(4)5)6)`

`1(2(3)4)5(6)` matches `(2(3)4)`

`1(2(3)4(5)6)7` matches `(2(3)4(5)6)`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A `stack` is an obvious choice here over regex.

Comment: Ah, that's right. Didn't think of that pattern :-/.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This cannot be achieved with a regex. `stack` should be used instead (thanks to @CinCout).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I'm confused now. For me it's the answer and I think no additional information is needed. What should I do if I ask a question and the answer is "this cannot be done, use X instead"?